# Angular 4 - call function of component A from view of component B

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components. Component A contains a function I would like to call by clicking on a button in the view of component B. How do I solve this?

I tried something like:

View component B

```
<button (click)="MyApp.myFunction()">Click here</button>
```

app.component.ts   (name class= MyApp)

```
myFunction(){
   console.log("clicked the button");
}
```

Comment: do they have any parent child relationship ?

Comment: @RahulSingh If parent/child means that Component B extends Component A, than they do not have an parent/child relationship

Comment: My answer should work then @xseriff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there is a parent/child relationship. In that case you use the @Output() to pass info to the parent.

Steps to take: 
 - Add an output property to the child component 
 - In the buttonClicked method on the child component, emit an event using the output property with the info you would like to pass to the parent
 - On the  element in the parent component's template, bind to the output property and call a handler function on the parent controller, passing in the value emitted from the child
 - In the handler function you created in step 3, set a property to the value received from the child component

So this would mean:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `<button (click)="buttonClicked()">Click me!</button>`
})
export class ChildComponent{
    @Output() buttonClick = new EventEmitter();  
    buttonClicked() {
        this.buttonClick.emit();
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <child (buttonClick)="buttonClickedHandler($event)"></child>
    `
})
export class ParentComponent{
    buttonClickedHandler(data) {
        console.log('Hello world!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can it in many ways [**Shared Services**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) or using [**Event emitters**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event) or this

**Component B**

```
<button (click)="myFunction()">Click here</button>

myFunction(){
    let component = new ComponentB();
    component.myFunctionA();
}
```

**ComponentA**

```
myFunctionA(){
   console.log("called");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify an `@Output` EventEmitter for ComponentB, e.g. in component-b.ts:

```
@Output() onButtonClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Then add a click handler in component-b.ts:

```
buttonClick() {
    this.onButtonClick.emit();
}
```

Then, in component-a.html, you can add a binding for the `onButtonClick` event:

```
(onButtonClick)="someHandler()"
```

And in component-a.ts you can add the other handler:

```
someHandler() {
    console.log('component-b button click');
}
```